# Android prepare waiting mechanism or correct synchronize to service

Tags: android

in my Android project i try to prepare waiting mechanism or correct synchronize to `intent service` to handle multi concurrency requests user. for example after click on button, my application try to get data on server with `Service`,

after click on the button, user maybe try to click on that again, for manage this operation i coding below sample to handle multi concurrency requests user, such as waiting to finish request with create an requests path.

but in this code i cont know how to create requests stack, that means they must run by order's requests.

## *now is my code correct?*

**Volley Simple Singleton Class:**

```
public class CustomVolleyRequestQueue {

    private static CustomVolleyRequestQueue mInstance;
    private static Context                  context;
    private        RequestQueue             mRequestQueue;

    private CustomVolleyRequestQueue(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequestQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CustomVolleyRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            // start the volley request queue
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
}
```

**Intent Service:**

```
public class WebService extends IntentService {
    public static final String REQUEST_TAG = "SimpleWebServiceBlockingRequest";
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    private Object       isReceiveMessagesLock;

    public WebService() {
        super("WebService");
    }

    public WebService(String name) {
        super("WebService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
            if (data != null) {
                String url = data.getString("url");
                synchronized (isReceiveMessagesLock) {
                    if (isReceiveMessagesLock != null) {
                        return;
                    } else {
                        try {
                            isReceiveMessagesLock.wait();
                            startParsingTask(url); //receiving start
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void startParsingTask(final String url) {
        Thread prepaire_request_thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                ThreadB    request_from_servcer_thread = new ThreadB(getApplicationContext(), url);
                JSONObject json_object                 = null;
                try {
                    json_object = request_from_servcer_thread.execute().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (json_object != null) {
                    Log.e("OUTPUT: ", json_object.toString());
                }
            }
        };
        prepaire_request_thread.start();
    }

    private class ThreadB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
        private Context context;
        private String fetch_url = "";

        public ThreadB(Context ctx, String url) {
            context = ctx;
            this.fetch_url = url;
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final RequestFuture<JSONObject> futureRequest = RequestFuture.newFuture();
            mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext())
                    .getRequestQueue();
            final JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method
                    .GET, fetch_url,
                    new JSONObject(), futureRequest, futureRequest);
            jsonRequest.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);
            mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
            try {
                return futureRequest.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

## POST UPDATED:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        if (data != null) {
            String url = data.getString("url");
            startParsingTask(url); //receiving start
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IntentService already handles one call per time, you don't need syncronize or anything else.

Volley supports also multiple calls, so you won't have any problem of concurrency at all.

After that, if you are calling APIs, you may want to try retrofit ( http://square.github.io/retrofit/ ) or at least use GSON to deserialize JSON data.

Comment: thanks, post updated, please review that again, i removed `synchronized` from `onHandleIntent`

Comment: ... my answer still applies. I would replace all your code with a line of retrofit

Comment: `Volley` by default can use cache and create offline data for json requests and images, if device dont have internet connection. i can't find any document about this mechanism for `retrofit`

Comment: ok. You're still using an intentservice, a thread and an async task.. for something that volley can do without any of that :) 

See for example this: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

Comment: i can find difference between my code and your link